# textbox allowing Decimals limit to 2 using javascript

Tags: javascript, decimal

I have a problem of limiting value after  decimal in a textbox to 2.

I don't want to use regex.
 can anybody help me how to achieve this?

I am not allowing the characters and limiting decimal point to 1,

Here is my code:

```
function CheckNumeric(e) {      
if (window.event) // IE 
    {
        if ((e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) & e.keyCode != 8 & !(e.keyCode == 46 && e.target.value.indexOf(".") == -1)) {
            event.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { // Fire Fox
        if ((e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) & e.which != 8 & !(e.which == 46 && e.target.value.indexOf(".") == -1)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
    }
  }
```

and Here is my Html Code:

```
 @Html.TextBox("CostperSeat", (object)item.CostperSeat, new{onkeypress="CheckNumeric(event); ", maxlength=10, style = "width:60px" })
```

Comment: Can we see an example of expected behaviour? Such as, what would be permitted, what should fail? Also, by "textbox" do you mean `<textarea>` or `<input type="text"/>` ?

Comment: 2.34, 2.01, 2.0 ,289365.15 these Should be true      and 12.23322, 2.4566, 2.85644666 anything like this should fail.

Comment: <input type="text"/> only.  onKeypressevent only it should not allow more than 2 values after decimal.

Comment: Okay, and why don't you want to use `RegExp` for this? It looks to me that the amount of logic behind a non-RegExp solution will require much more processing.

Comment: i am not comfortable with regex. I should not allow when user entering morethan 2 values after decimals. I think with regex it is not possible.

Comment: Sure you can with _RegExp_, rather than preventing the keydown, what you do is: On _keypress_ and _keyup_ use `this.value = this.value.replace(/(\.\d{2})\d+/g, "$1");`. To prevent pasting, you may want to consider other events too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider as below:

Textbox Control in .aspx page like as below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="180px" onkeypress="return onlyDotsAndNumbers(this,event)"></asp:TextBox>
```

See, onkeypress event, call one of javascript function as below:

```
function onlyDotsAndNumbers(txt, event) {
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode   
    if (charCode == 46) {
        if (txt.value.indexOf(".") < 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    if (txt.value.indexOf(".") > 0) {
        var txtlen = txt.value.length;
        var dotpos = txt.value.indexOf(".");
        if ((txtlen - dotpos) > 2)
            return false;
    }

    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

It would be helpful to you.

Comment: what happens if you paste? What happens if you type the number without a `.` then add the `.` last?

Comment: after entering two decimal values it is not allowing any values, prefix we can't change. we should be able to edit prefix